# How to Include Space For Column Name in Bind()

Tags: asp.net

Currently My Column Name is RequestDate, But I have changed Column Name in DataTable as "Request Date". Just Added Space. Now How to Include space in Bind()

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRequestDate" Text='<%# Bind("RequestDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Because If I put Space in Bind as Bind(Request Date) It giving me A call to Bind was not well formatted Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like below

```
gridview1.Columns[ColumnIndex].HeaderText = "Request Date";
```

You can use `Bound Field` and set `DataField` and `HeaderText` if you like.

In you `Data Table` keep it **RequestDate** use `BoundField` and set it's `HeaderText` as follows

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="RequestDate" HeaderText="Request Date" >
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `EVAL` instead of bind